# Sets Venn diagram total elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following set theory problem:

There are 3 vacation activities:

1. Beach (A)
2. Swimming pool (B)
3. Ecological (C)

These are the date collected:

- 73 persons participated (sample)
- 50 prefer swimming pool activities
- 20 prefer beach activities
- 30 prefer ecological activities
- 16 prefer swimming pool and ecological activities
- 9 prefer beach and ecological activities
- 6 prefer all the activities simultaneously
- 7 prefer only beach

I have built the following Venn diagram:

[image: Venn diagram]

But if I sum up all of the values from the intersections (3, 6 and 10) and the values unique in A (11), B (34) and C (11)...

...it doesn't total 73 (universal set). Why?

Comment: Do any of the 73 participants have "no preference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven’t been explicitly told how many people prefer beach and swimming pool activities.  You can, however, infer what that number must be ($2$) from the work that you’ve already done.  Your number $11$ in the $A$ circle is wrong because you’ve been given that only $7$ people prefer only beach.

Using the principle of inclusion and exclusion, $73=20+50+30-16-9-x+6=81-x,$ so $x=8$.  There are $6$ people who prefer all three activities so there are $2$ people who prefer beach and swimming pool activities.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the number of participants with **no preference** at all, which is not quite the same thing as preferring all equally.  $$N=A^\complement\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement\\~~~=(A\cup B\cup C)^\complement$$

- $\nu(A\cup B\cup C\cup N)=73$ persons participated (sample)
- $\nu(A)=50$ prefer swimming pool activities
- $\nu(B)=20$ prefer beach activities
- $\nu(C)=30$ prefer ecological activities
- $\nu(A\cap C)=16$ prefer swimming pool and ecological activities
- $\nu(B\cap C)=9$ prefer beach and ecological activities
- $\nu(A\cap B\cap C)= 6$ prefer all the activities simultaneously
- $\nu(B\smallsetminus(A\cup C))=7$ perfer only beach.

$\begin{align}\nu(B\smallsetminus(A\cup C)) &= \nu(B)-\nu(B\cap (A\cup C))\\ &=\nu(B)-\nu((A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)) \\ &=\nu(B)-\nu(A\cap B)-\nu(B\cap C)+\nu(A\cap B\cap C)\\7&=20-\nu(A\cap B)-9+6\\\nu(A\cap B)&=11\\[3ex]\nu(A\cup B\cup C\cup N) &=\nu(N)+\nu(A)+\nu(B)+\nu(C)-\nu(A\cap B)-\nu(A\cap C)-\nu(B\cap C)+\nu(A\cap B\cap C)\\73 &= \nu(N)+ 50+20+30-11-16-9+6\\\nu(N)&=3\end{align}$

Comment: There’s an error in the diagram.  Only $7$ people, not $11$, prefer only the beach.  The natural assumption in a problem like this is that everyone has *some* preference, and that assumption holds here.